# edit option for job messages/replies

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, comment-replies, jobs-messages

- Provide edit option for job message or replies. That helps to review and edit if any changes need to do.
- Edit option can be temporary time based or until recruiter replies to it.
- Providing more options with good XD will help for better interactions.